# Dividing and multiplying by the derivative in an integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y' + y = y^{-2}$

I divided everything by $y^{-2}$ and let $v = y^3$, then solved as normal. (I relaced the $y^2$ with $y^{2}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{dv}{dy}$ after differentiating the $v$.

After $v$ substitution, $\frac{1}{3}\frac{dv}{dx} + v = 1$ and $\frac{1}{3}\int \:\frac{dv}{1-v}=\int \:dx$

Now how can I solve this if you need the derivative of $v$ in order to get a log?
Can I just multiply and divide by $\frac{dv}{dx}$? Can someone finish it off?

Comment: What do you think is not correct here?(Or what is the thing whose explanation you need)

Comment: multiplying and dividing by something other than a constant

Comment: $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{v^\prime}{1-v}dx  = -\ln(1-v)$ You are not multiplying by any number here

Comment: but $v'$ is not in the orriginal integral so you are changing the value if you only multiply by $v'$

Comment: $ v^{\prime}$ is the derivative of v

Comment: what actually $\int  v(x)dv$ means is $ \int v^{\prime} v(x) dx $

Comment: Oh I didnt know that. Thanks I will try that

Comment: @user71207 see bottom of my answer for how to proceed from where you left off.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking to solve the equation? If that is the case, this is separable.

$$\begin{split}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{1-y^3}{y^2}\\
\frac{dx}{dy}&=\frac{y^2}{1-y^3}\\
\int dx&=\int\frac{y^2}{1-y^3}dy\end{split}$$

Let $u=1-y^3,du=-3y^2dy$

$$\begin{split}x&=-\frac 1 3\int\frac 1 udu\\
&=-\frac 1 3\ln|u|+c\\
x&=-\frac 1 3\ln|1-y^3|+c\end{split}$$

---

Equivalently, from where you left off, let $u=1-v,du=-dv$. Then

$$\begin{split}-\frac 1 3\int\frac 1 u du&=x+c\\
-\frac 1 3 \ln|1-v|&=\\
-\frac 1 3\ln|1-y^3|&=x+c\end{split}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as

$$\dfrac{1}{3}\int \:\dfrac{dv}{1-v} = -\dfrac{1}{3}\log(1-v)$$

Comment: The question doesn't ask for an antiderivative

Comment: What does it ask then?

Comment: why can we integrate like this